# NSScrollView: Does it retain -documentView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

Does a release of `NSScrollView` object release document view object as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a NSView will retain it's subviews, and that includes `NSScrollView`'s `-contentView`, `-documentView`, etc.

So, when the `NSScrollView` deallocates, the `documentView` will get `-release`'d

Comment: thanks, so If I have a tableview as the document view of a scrollview does the tableviews delegate and data source objects also get released?

Comment: @Manish I don't know how the properties are created, if they are strong or weak.